# JavaScript Array of arrays: not defined elemnts

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been developing a canvas application in javascript in which I need to define a 9 cell grid (3x3) and in each grid have a canvas element.

The thing is, I have already an array called grid which has the data to represent the size of each cell.

```
var grid = new Array();

grid[0] = {x:[0, elemWidth], y:[0, elemHeight]};
grid[1] = {x:[elemWidth, elemWidth*2], y:[0, elemHeight]};
grid[2] = {x:[(elemWidth*2), sWidth], y:[0, elemHeight]};
grid[3] = {x:[0, elemWidth], y:[elemHeight+1,elemHeight*2]};
grid[4] = {x:[elemWidth, elemWidth*2], y:[elemHeight, elemHeight*2]};
grid[5] = {x:[(elemWidth*2), sWidth], y:[elemHeight, elemHeight*2]};
grid[6] = {x:[0, elemWidth], y:[(elemHeight*2), sHeight]};
grid[7] = {x:[elemWidth, elemWidth*2], y:[(elemHeight*2), sHeight]};
grid[8] = {x:[(elemWidth*2), sWidth], y:[(elemHeight*2), sHeight]};
```

This produces the following output on Chrome Inspector:

[image: inspector output]

As far as I can tell, I should be able to obtain the x and y values by using the following code

```
canvas[i].fillRect(grid[i].x[0], grid[i].y[0], grid[i].x[1], grid[i].y[1]);
canvas[i].strokeRect(grid[i].x[0], grid[i].y[0], grid[i].x[1], grid[i].y[1]);
```

and each should give me the corresponding values.

I can't understand why I can get everything OK when on `canvas[0]` (everything renders on the browser) but when it comes to the subsequent `canvas[i]`(with i>0) won't render and I get an undefined value although the HTML produces the tags for each canvas element.

Am I doing anything wrong declaring the arrays?

#### EDIT

Made a few changes to the code just for the sake of simplicity and readability:

```
function createCanvas() {

/* criar grelha aqui */

var sWidth = window.innerWidth; //- 50;
var sHeight = window.innerHeight; //- 50;

var elemWidth = sWidth / 3;
var elemHeight = sHeight / 3;

var grid = new Array();

var row1 = [0, elemHeight];
var row2 = [elemHeight, elemHeight*2];
var row3 = [elemHeight*2, sHeight];

var col1 = [0, elemWidth];
var col2 = [elemWidth, elemWidth*2];
var col3 = [elemWidth*2, sWidth];

grid[0] = [col1, row1];
grid[1] = [col2, row1];
grid[2] = [col3, row1];
grid[3] = [col1, row2];
grid[4] = [col2, row2];
grid[5] = [col3, row2];
grid[6] = [col1, row3];
grid[7] = [col2, row3];
grid[8] = [col3, row3];

for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    var c = document.getElementById('content');
    var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    newCanvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas'+i);
    c.appendChild(newCanvas);
    canvas[i] = new Canvas('canvas'+i, 0, function() {});
        canvas[i].clear();
        canvas[i].setAutoResize(true);
        canvas[i].canvasElement.width = elemWidth - 2;
        canvas[i].canvasElement.height = elemHeight - 2;


        canvas[i].fillStyle('#000000');
        canvas[i].strokeStyle('#FFFFFF');

    canvas[i].fillRect(grid[i][0], grid[i][0], grid[i][2], grid[i][3]);
    canvas[i].strokeRect(grid[i][0], grid[i][0], grid[i][4], grid[i][5]);
```

This code is much more complete than the previous version which only had a little bit of the function

Meanwhile I managed to get 3 cells to render (although the 3 cell, which should be 1x3 is actually a 2x1 because somehow the rendering isn't happening properly, which I think might be a CSS problem)

#### EDIT2

Again I've made some changes to the code above. And new screenshot of the grid array expanded view.
[image: grid array expanded view]

Comment: I think the problem is in canvas, not in grid. You should first check canvas object.

Comment: Remember that the origin point when drawing to canvas is 0,0. It doesn't matter where that canvas sits on the page, you will still draw from that position. Don't try and offset based on where the canvas is positioned on the page.

Comment: @swemon What makes you say that? I'm using [canvas-lib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/html-canvas-lib/). You think you could take 10 minutes to take a look at it?

Comment: @MattStone That shouldn't be a problem I think since apparently everything is working properly. The grid is correctly positioned, just the canvases that won't render where they should (inside the grid cell)

Comment: (unrelated to the question, but) This is unnecessary: `var col1 = new Array(); col1 = [0, elemWidth];` You're defining a `new Array` and then defining a newer array with `[]`. If you want a new array, empty or not, just use `[]` notation.

Comment: @Zed_Blade I'm not sure if you understand Mattt's point. Your grids are correctly positioned, yes, but on _every_ `canvas`, you still have to `fillRect` from `(0,0)`, not like `(grid.width*2,grid.height*2)` on `grid[8]`.

Comment: _"I get an undefined value"_ - Where/when does the undefined value occur? Are you talking about an error in your console, or...? Where/how is the `canvas` variable defined?

Comment: @Passerby So is there any way I can define the starting point for the canvas to be the same as the grid corresponding to the intended cell?

Comment: @nnnnnn Managed to solve that in the meanwhile.

Comment: @Zed_Blade Not that I'm aware of, sorry.

Comment: @ianpgall I thought that so.. The first version I posted should work just fine right?

Comment: Yes, what I'm pointing out has no real effect on whatever problems you're having (it seems like). I just wanted to point out that instead of declaring your variables twice technically, you should really only use `[]`

Comment: @Passerby think I could manage to get the intended effect by using some kind of offset?

Comment: @Zed_Blade Can you instead mark the "right" coordination into `grid[]`? From your posted code I think you're actually making 9 identical canvas and placing them in a grid. So you can actually draw rectangles with the same coordination on all 9 canvas.

Comment: @Passerby what do you mean by right coordination? The points to the right where the canvas should start?

Comment: @Zed_Blade Oops, I just mean "correct". Instead of altering how `canvasContext.fillRect()`, I would suggest you to make "correct" coordinate in `grid[]` in the first place. Calculate the offset before assign them into `grid[]`.

Comment: @Passerby I've made more changes to the code,and trying to do what you say.But I must b missing something.Instead of the offset I'm telling the canvas to render inside the grid & apparently (on Inspector) the offset values are correct.I did notice that `grid[0]` has 2 elems & that each of these elems has an array with offset values (the intended offset values).In order to use the corresponding value for the start point,which is in `grid[0], elem[0]` shouldn't I just call `grid[0][0]`?I've never been good with arrays & this seems to confirm it.(Also,new image w the expanded view of the grid)

Comment: @Zed_Blade No, `grid[0][0]` is `col1`, which is still an array (`[0,elemWidth]`). I think you're making things a little too complicated. Multidimensional array can be frustrating if your mind is not clear. I would suggest you to put down your code for a while, review the whole grid and rectangles you're trying to draw, point out the drawing points, and hopefully figure out (reinvent) a `grid[]` that you're confident about _why_ it should look like that.

Comment: @Passerby What if I define a single canvas, with 9 fillRect which are equal to the grid already defined? Just by thought do you think I should be able to prevent an action to occur if the touchEvent moves out of the grid cell bounds?

Comment: @Zed_Blade That would be much better. But it can not "prevent" an event moves out, you have to monitor the touch point to determine which cell to react. You can draw several "cell"s altogether in one canvas, one coordinate system by this way, if you allow users to "touch" multiple "cell"s consequently.

Comment: @MattStone You were right, that was the correct answer all along. Thanks.

Comment: @Zed_Blade No worries, glad you solved your issues.